# Cassandra: For brute force write which one is better - ANY or ONE?

Tags: cassandra, astyanax, cassandra-2.0

[This link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) in Cassandra's documentation describes the different consistency level's for write. If I am okay with data-loss and want the best write performance possible on a 3 node cluster with replication of 2 - which one should I choose between ANY and ONE? Which one is better for brute force performance of writes? I use Astyanax client library and it uses a default of CL_ONE. But it also has an option of CL_ANY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANY will give you the fastest write performance if you don't care about possible loss, but you can easily overload your nodes with it such that you cause extra loss.  So if you are going to have sustained writes to your cluster, then I would recommend ONE.  If your sustained write load isn't going to be such that you can't keep up, then you should be fine using ANY.